# Symmetry of the partial derivative of a diffeomorphic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, symmetry, diffeomorphism

I am wondering if there is symmetry among the single partial derivative of a multivariate diffeomorphic function.

Let $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ be a diffeomorphism defined over $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (it is a d-dimensional multivariate function). Let $\mathbf{V} \in \mathcal{X}$ be some d-dimensional set of variables.

Say we have the following constraint on one of the single partial derivatives:

$\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial f_{i}(\mathbf{V})} = 0$, does this imply that $\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{V})}{\partial V_i} = 0$?

If so, is there a name for such a result? If this does not hold for a diffeomorphism, then are there any general conditions that would make this property hold?

The closest thing I could find was something about the symmetry of mixed partial-derivatives (i.e. taking two partial derivatives) [Symmetry of mixed partial derivatives.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237196/symmetry-of-mixed-partial-derivatives).